# Using avg() function in SQL query returns only one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT aname, avg(salary) 
FROM aircraft, certified, employees 
WHERE cruisingrange > 1000 AND ((certified.eid = employees.eid) = (aircraft.aid = certified.aid));
```

In one column, I am trying to display the aircraft names (aname) of all aircraft with cruising ranges over 1000 miles (cruisingrange > 1000). In the other column, I am trying to display the average salary (avg(salary)) of certified pilots (certified.eid = employees.eid) who are certified to fly that aircraft in particular (entire conditional after AND). However, it's conglomerating all the salaries into a single value and returning that, therefore I am only given a table with two columns and one row instead many rows (it only displays one aircraft name as well).

These SQL queries separately work just fine, though:

```
SELECT aname 
FROM aircraft 
WHERE cruisingrange > 1000;

SELECT avg(salary)
FROM employees, certified
WHERE employees.eid = certified.eid;

SELECT DISTINCT aname
FROM aircraft, certified
WHERE certified.aid = aircraft.aid;
```

How do I write a query that does what I'm supposed to do? I just started self-teaching SQL today so sorry if the answer is pretty obvious. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If you're teaching yourself SQL you could pick a more standard DB than MySQL.  Each DB has their differences and foibles but MySQL is a stand-out in weird behaviour, especially around grouping.  I'd recommend Postgres or one of the free SQL Server versions to start off on the right footing.

Comment: @LoztInSpace I see, I will look into it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using MySQL, so use `GROUP BY` correctly:

```
SELECT aname, avg(salary) 
FROM aircraft a JOIN
     certified c
     ON a.aid = c.aid JOIN
     employees e
     ON c.eid = e.eid
WHERE cruisingrange > 1000 
GROUP BY aname;
```

Based on your query, you don't seem to understand SQL very well.  So let's start there.  Here is some advice:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases (abbreviations).
- Qualify all column names (I can't in the above query, because I don't know where the columns come from).
- Don't use `DISTINCT` until you understand SQL.  It has big effects on performance and does strange unexpected things, sometimes.

So, what is happening with your query?  Basically, consider this related query:

```
SELECT aname, avg(salary) 
FROM aircraft a JOIN
     certified c
     ON a.aid = c.aid JOIN
     employees e
     ON c.eid = e.eid
WHERE cruisingrange > 1000 ;
```

How many rows does it return?  Well . . . in most databases, it would return 0 rows and an error.  This is an aggregation query, but the SQL engine does know what to do with `aname`.

MySQL allows this syntax, returning one row (because it is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`).  The value of `aname` is taken from an *indeterminate* row.

Hence, when you add `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT`, it has no effect.  The query already returns only one row, so it is, by definition, distinct.

Comment: This helps me out a lot, thanks! And you're right, I am very new and awful at SQL. So I'll look into learning about joins and grouping.